# Apache output flush configuration

Tags: apache, perl, output, flush

I have the following perl script on two different servers, Centos and Debian, both running Apache web server:

```
$|++;
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

for ($i=1; $i<=10;$i++) {
    print "$i\n";
    sleep(1);
}
print "Done.\n";
```

On centos with Apache/2.2.3 and perl v5.8.8 output flush works fine and I can see the counter progression in browser as it proceeds.

On Debian Apache/2.4.10 and perl v5.20.2 output flush is not working and I see the whole page in the browser only after 10 sec.

Is there a way to configure apache in order to flush the output as on centos?

Comment: Try using `select->autoflush(1)` instead of depending on a previously set magical value.

Comment: @choroba, Is that a style suggestion? Cause that won't make any functional difference. (And if you want to avoid the magic of `$|++;`, all you need is `$| = 1;`. Obviously, `select->autoflush(1);` is clearer, though, but far more expensive as it involves three calls to `select` and two assignments to `$|`.)

Comment: Re "*Is there a way to configure apache*", I confirm that it's not in a difference in Perl that's causing this.

Comment: Note that `use IO::Handle ();` is required for `autoflush` to be callable as a method on handles in 5.8.8. My preference would be `\*STDOUT->autoflush(1);` as long as you know you are dealing with STDOUT, but you're right that it shouldn't make a functional difference.

Comment: select->autoflush(1); or \*STDOUT->autoflush(1); has no effect; I think it is an apache setting not a difference in perl.

Comment: For regular pages this is not a problem, but I run procedures that require hours to complete and with no output the browser close the connection after few minutes.

Comment: Re "*as long as you know you are dealing with STDOUT*", I'm with @choroba on this one. If you print to the selected handle, you should autoflush the selected  handle, even if you "happen to know" STDOUT is selected.

Comment: Compare the output, especially the headers. Is Apache 2.4 using compression by default when 2.2 is not? Compression enabled would nullify flushing. Look if `mod_gzip` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To flush the output I had to disable both varnish and mod_deflate.

Thank you for helping me out.

cl.